# Debugging problem

Tags: vb.net

I have made some changes to my project, when I debug, application seems to run the old .exe file, not the updated.  I know it happens when there are some errors but I do not get any error messages also I checked the error list, it does not show any errors.

I also re-started Visual Studio, but nothing has changed.

Please advise.
Thanks and best regards,
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sometimes happens. You can try two thing:

- In the menu, under “Project” (I think), go to “Clean solution”
- If that doesn’t help, go to the folder where your project is stored, go into the `Debug` folder and delete the exe file.